# A basic doubt on open set

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I see in a book the following is claimed : If $E$ is an uncountable subset of $\Bbb R^n$ and then $S \cap E$ is open where $S$ is open. Why ? The intercept from the book is as follows :

$E$ is an uncountable subset of $\Bbb R^n$. Let $P$ be the set of all condensation points of $E$ (points every neighbourhood of which contains uncountably many elements from $E$). Take $p \in P$. suppose $p$ is not a limit point point $P$. Then there exists a neighbourhood $N_r(p)$ which will contain atmost one element namely $p$ of $P$. Then it is claimed that $N_r(p)^* \cap E$ is open. $N_r(p)^*= N_r(p)-\{p\}$

Answer (score 1):

Not true - take $S$ to be an open interval and $E$ to be the irrationals.

Comment: Carpetis : Plz see the intercept from the book.

Comment: @Prasenjit: I don't follow the argument - is there more context? Is this part of a proof by contradiction? I'm pretty sure the set of condensation points has no isolated points, so such a $p$ cannot exist.

Comment: yes, this is a proof by contradiction

Answer (score 0):

$N_r(p)^*\cap E$ is open in the relative (or subspace) topology that $E$ inherits from $\Bbb R^n$, but it is not necessarily open in $\Bbb R^n$ itself; if the book makes that claim, it’s simply wrong. The proof that $p$ is a limit point of $P$ should continue as follows.

Let $\mathscr{B}=\{B_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ be a countable base for $\Bbb R^n$. (I’m assuming that at this point you’ve already proved that $\Bbb R^n$ has a countable base for its topology.) Let $x\in N_r(p)^*$; then $x\notin P$, so $x$ has an open nbhd $U_x$ such that $U_x\cap E$ is countable. $N_r(p)^*$ is open, so there is an $n(x)\in\Bbb N$ such that $x\in B_{n(x)}\subseteq U_x\cap N_r(p)^*$; clearly $B_{n(x)}\cap E$ is countable.

Next, observe that

$$N_r(p)^*=\bigcup_{x\in N_r(p)^*}B_{n(x)}\;,$$

and hence

$$N_r(p)^*\cap E=\bigcup_{x\in N_r(p)^*}(B_{n(x)}\cap E)\;,\tag{1}$$

$\mathscr{B}$ is countable, so there are only countably many **distinct** sets $B_{n(x)}$ appearing in the union in $(1)$. The righthand side is therefore the union of countably many countable sets and is therefore itself countable. But then $N_r(p)^*\cap E$ is countable, and hence so is $N_r(p)\cap E$, contradicting the assumption that $p\in P$.